# Optionally join tables in SQL with possible NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, option-type

I have 3 tables:

```
DECLARE @PRODUCT TABLE(PRODUCTID INT,TITLE NVARCHAR(MAX),BRANDID INT,SPECID INT)

DECLARE @SPEC TABLE(SPECID INT,TITLE NVARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @BRAND TABLE(BRANDID INT,TITLE NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @PRODUCT 
SELECT 1,'TV',1,8 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'PC',2,12

INSERT INTO @BRAND
SELECT 1,'SAMSUN' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'GRUNDING'

INSERT INTO @SPEC 
SELECT 8,'PRICE' UNION ALL
SELECT 9,'WEIGHT'
```

I want to get result from **@PRODUCT** table if at least one of **@BRAND** or **@SPEC** 
tables have data. So I tried with **LEFT JOIN** like this:

```
SELECT  p.* ,
        s.*,
        b.*
FROM    @PRODUCT p
         LEFT JOIN @BRAND b ON b.BRANDID = p.BRANDID AND b.BRANDID IS NOT NULL
         LEFT JOIN @SPEC s ON s.SPECID = p.SPECID AND s.SPECID IS NOT NULL
```

but couldn't get desired result. For data I provided I want to filter only product with **Title TV**. So, I want to apply optional **join**. I mean if @BRAND or @SPEC table  have data, or both of them have data, it should filter products based on that conditions.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

**EDIT**
As per requst I provide more data for tables.

```
INSERT INTO @PRODUCT 
SELECT 1,'TV',1,8 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'PC',2,12 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'PHONE',505,10

INSERT INTO @BRAND
SELECT 1,'SAMSUN' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'GRUNDING' 

INSERT INTO @SPEC 
SELECT 8,'PRICE' UNION ALL
SELECT 9,'WEIGHT' UNION ALL
SELECT 10,'SIZE'
```

For this data I want to get only row for Product with ProductID=1. So, I need only to select this one row in this example.

Comment: Values in SPEC and BRAND tables are not important semantically right now, because this example is simplified version of originally query. I just want to point that I should get data from Product table for those criterias that satisfied Brand and Spec table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works. I just tried it. The only thing I have changed is move `WHERE s.SPECID IS NOT NULL` from `ON CLAUSE` to `WHERE CLAUSE`. Having it in the `ON CLAUSE` of a `LEFT JOIN` only restricts it for the join but still returns the row. Having it in the `WHERE CLAUSE` filters the row.

```
 DECLARE @SpecCount INT 
 DECLARE @BrandCount INT 

 SELECT @SpecCount = COUNT(*) FROM @SPEC 
 SELECT @BrandCount = COUNT(*) FROM @BRAND 

 SELECT p.*, 
     s.*, 
     b.* 
 FROM @PRODUCT p 
 LEFT JOIN @BRAND b 
     ON b.BRANDID = p.BRANDID 
 LEFT JOIN @SPEC s 
     ON s.SPECID = p.SPECID 
 WHERE ((s.SPECID IS NOT NULL OR @SpecCount = 0) 
     AND (b.BRANDID IS NOT NULL OR @BrandCount = 0))
```

Comment: This is not desired result. JOIN should work in these cases:1. when one of SPEC or BRAND tables is empty,2.in case when all of three tables have data

Comment: Can you add more rows in your question and also provide the output you want?

Comment: Updated the answer.. Is this what you want?

Comment: With query you provided you get NULL on SPECID column and that is not desired result. If you could write query that remove that row that would be ok. And also to be more clear, SPEC or BRAND table can be empty so query should work in that case too.

Comment: As I said above can you add more rows (different scenario) in your example in the question and provide the desired result.

Comment: Ah... So you want PRODUCTs that have both SPEC and BRAND??? I updated the answer if that's what you are looking for...

Comment: No. Can you comment out insert statement for Brand table. If you do that, I want to get result for with 2 rows with values TV and PHONE.Since Product and Spec tables are matched on SpecId column.

Comment: That's what I get on commenting the insert statement for brand table with my previous answer (i.e. using OR) . TV and PHONE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43710/discussion-between-adarsh-shah-and-black123)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for correctly, you should do the joins first then filter. Something like:

```
SELECT
    p.* ,
    s.*,
    b.*
FROM
    @PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN
    @BRAND b
ON
    b.BRANDID = p.BRANDID
LEFT JOIN
    @SPEC s
ON
    s.SPECID = p.SPECID
WHERE
    b.BRANDID IS NOT NULL OR s.SPECID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This will give an error... b.BRANDID in the WHERE clause needs to also check for NULL. Look at my answer below.